# Fraunhofer solar spectra data

Tags: untagged

I'd like to display directly the [Fraunhofer solar spectrum](https://winsco.com/product/solar-spectrum-chart/), complete with absorption lines.

I couldn't find it [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpectralLineData.html).